# Using AngularJS with SpringMVC - Why and How?

Tags: javascript, spring, angularjs, spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I am new to web development and recently came up reading about AngularJS and SpringMVC and a few other frameworks. As far as I could understand, AngularJS implements the MVC on client side and Spring implements MVC on the server side.

And in another tutorial I read about using AngularJS with SpringMVC. This confused me a little.

Why do we need to implement MVC pattern on the server side when its already done on the client side?

If spring returns a view, then how is this passed on to AngularJS? Or what is the necessity for returning a view when Angular itself has a view to present?

Also, isn't having all the controllers and services on the client side (AngularJS) lead to security issues, because there are cases of security breaches for JavaScript. And also, wouldn't having those on client side load up the client?

I am a bit confused. Please correct me if I am wrong somewhere. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a previous job I worked extensively with AngularJS and Spring. We used our Spring for the back-end exclusively as a RESTful web application framework. AngularJS was our front-end and would do all the views and client-side logic.

I won't go into detail on how AngularJS implements MVC, but AngularJS provides very good tutorials on their website where you can get the feel for how they do things.

AngularJS is an excellent choice and a fantastic framework. They have a huge community and are continually improving/rebuilding themselves. They are backed by Google and are one of the most reliable and useful frameworks I've ever worked with.

As for security/client side. You need to use some type of authentication to protect your site. Code minification is important as well. Its important to note that the client side is much faster than it used to be. JavaScript accelerators and better browsers have made Javascript extremely fast even on mobile. You can do allot of lifting on the client side without slowing down the user experience. Its also important to design good endpoints for your back-end which will simplify the work you have to do in your front-end controllers.

[Here](http://fdietz.github.io/recipes-with-angular-js/consuming-external-services/consuming-restful-apis.html) is a good example on how to consume a RESTful API with angular resource.

Spring actually has a tutorial on their website showing how to consume a Spring Web Service with Angular JS. [Here is the link.](http://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest-angularjs/) In the tutorial they show how to do this without angular resource, I suggest to not follow it explicitly, using angular-resource allows you to centralize all your API calls to one place and then inject them throughout your web-application as needed. This helps keep your code more modular and prevents the nasty refactoring process that occurs when you have endpoints scattered throughout dozens of files.